# How can I tell if the Window Handle is main window handle?

Tags: winapi

Hello hello Thank you for reading my question.

I am currently building a program which detects new window creation / termination.

Gratefully, I have successfully managed to implement WinEvents and SetWinEventHook to capture events and filter window creation and termination.

However, I am facing a challenging task to accurately filter correct Window handles.

For example when putty.exe runs, many handles including main handle, button handle...etc are captured by my function.

However, I only desire to filter main Window handle.

Therefore, I used if statement as following.

```
if (event == EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE && GetParent(hwnd)==NULL)
```

This seemed to work for a while.

However, this if statement prevented my program from capturing child window's main handle.

Is there any way to tell if Window handle(HWND) belongs to main window?

My colleague tells me to implement GetWindowLong and compare style.

But, I have no clue about that.

If anyone knows answer, please help.

Again thanks for reading this question.

Comment: You can't both "*filter main Window handle*" only, and capture "*child window's main handle*" too. Before asking *how* to do it you'll have to decide *what* exactly you want to do.

Comment: There is no such concept as a *"main window"* in the Windows API. The fundamentals are explained at [window features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features). Any program can create zero or more *"top-level windows"*. The system doesn't subscribe any additional semantics to those windows, and certainly does not arbitrarily pick or mark any of those as a *"main window"*. .NET's [MainWindowHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle) is just a guess.

Comment: Maybe you could use [`GetClassName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname) check the Window class name if it is the class name you register or the control name in [Control Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/individual-control-info).